Camera deactivated if I change "Shell" in MAUI application
I have a MAUI application with two "Shells". On the main page I have a button that takes me to the second "Shell"
async private void OnCameraClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//CameraPage");
}

In "CameraPage.xaml"
<zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView x:Name="cameraBarcodeReaderView"
WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200" Margin="20"
HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
BarcodesDetected="BarcodesDetected" />

And "CameraPage.xaml.cs"
public CameraPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cameraBarcodeReaderView.Options = new BarcodeReaderOptions
    {
        Formats = BarcodeFormat.Code39 |
                  BarcodeFormat.Code128 |
                  BarcodeFormat.QrCode,
            AutoRotate = true,
            Multiple = true
        };
    }

When I go back to the main shell and then try to go back to the camera shell, the image no longer appears

My "AppShell.xaml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Title="MauiApp2">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="Camera"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CameraPage}"
        Route="CameraPage" />
</Shell>


Did you register the CameraPage as a singleton? Try making it transient and see if that works. Side note: The *AndExpand layout options are deprecated and will eventually be removed.

Please don't post large amounts of code in the comments, that's not readable and doesn't answer my question. Add it to the question instead. Try registering your page as a transient dependency as explained here. This should always give you a new instance when navigating to the page, i.e. call builder.Services.AddTransient<CameraPage>(); in MauiProgram.cs

By the way, in your question you're talking about "two Shells", you probably mean "two ShellContent" instances. Usually, there's only a single Shell that hosts different instances of ShellContent and pages.

Please help create Minimal, Reproducible Example and add it to your post, this will help reproduce and fix this issue.
